# CakePHP 3 find all where id matches OR in a array unknown length

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cart

I have a session cart where I add id and quantity in.

My array looks like this `$cart = [[1,1], [108,1] ,[50,2], [109,1]]`
First index is the Product ID and the second is the quantity.

I am trying to do a find where id is equal to my `array[0]`
As a test i explicit set the ids i want

I search through the manuel, i couldn't really find anything. I saw `matching()` but that isn't it either.

```
  $query = $this->Carts->Products->find('all')
        ->where(['id' => [1,108,50,109] ]);
```

One idea is do a foreach on $cart and just to do a query get(id) on each one? But that doesn't sound efficient.

Comment: thanks, I forgot what it was called, i have to review my SQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$query = $this->Carts->Products->find('all') ->where(['id IN' => $yourarray]);
```

simply use the IN clause